# How can I expand the dropdown list wider than the title

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown

I am trying to make a simple dropdown menu using Javascript that slides up and down when the user hovers over the title.

It all works OK as long as the dropdown items are no wider than the title.  But I cannot work out how to accommodate wider dropdown items, other than to hard code the width of all the items in the relevant list.

Is there a better way to do this (my code is below).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).click(function(event) {
    var text = $(event.target).text();
  });

  $("nav li").hover(
    function() {
      $(this)
        .find("ul>li")
        .stop()
        .slideDown(400);
    },

    function() {
      $(this)
        .find("ul>li")
        .stop()
        .slideUp(400);
    }
  );
});
```

```css
ul {
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; /* to prevent the menu indenting - ul has padding by default */
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: purple;
  width: 100px;
}

ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li li {
  background-color: purple;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: none;
}

ul li li:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Extra Extra Wide Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">FAQ</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In you css where `ul li li` add `width`

```
ul li li {
   background-color: purple;
   color: #fff;
   text-decoration: none;
   display: none;
   width: 200px;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
       $(document).click(function(event) {
           var text = $(event.target).text();
       });
    
       $('nav li').hover (
        function() {
         $(this).find('ul>li').stop().slideDown(400);
        },
    
        function() {
         $(this).find('ul>li').stop().slideUp(400);
        }
       );
     });
```

```css
ul {
        left: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0; /* to prevent the menu indenting - ul has padding by default */
        list-style: none;
        }
    
       ul li {
        float: left;
        height: 30px;
        line-height: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: purple;
        width: 100px;
        }
    
       ul li a {
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        }
     
       ul li li {
        background-color: purple;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: none;
            width: 200px
        }
    
       ul li li:hover {
        background-color: green;
        }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

      <div>
       <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Extra Extra Wide Link 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
          </ul>
         </li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQ</a>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
          </ul>
         </li>
            <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
        </ul>
       </nav> 
      </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  But then all my drop down lists will be 200px.  But I only need the width to increase if one of the items in the drop down list is wider than the title, as in the case of the Home menu, but not the FAQ menu in my example.